# ggplot list of plots to one pdf with different page layouts

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I want to produce a single pdf with many pages of ggplots. Using `gridExtra`, I can also build a page of plots with a `m x n` layout (`m` rows of plots, `n` columns of plots).

The function `ggsave` allows me to write a page of plots, even those that are built with `gridExtra` having the `m x n` layout.

Using [`arrangeGrob`](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/wiki/arrangeGrob) it is even possible to `ggsave` many pages to a single pdf, as long as each page has the same `m x n` layout.

I'm wondering how I can `ggsave` a list of plots that have different page layouts? For example, I have a list, `l`, with length 3 representing 3 pages.

`l[[1]]` is a page with a `2 x 2` layout and has 4 plots

`l[[2]]` is `2 x 1` with 2 plots

`l[[3]]` is only `1 x 1`

How could I hack `ggsave` so that I can write the list `l` into 1 pdf file with 3 pages having different layouts?  The plots should be displayed in landscape, so typically the command would have the form

```
ggsave("multipage.pdf", do.call(arrangeGrob, myplots[[i]]), width=11, height=8.5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the same class trick as `marrangeGrob`,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
pl <- lapply(1:7, function(i) ggplot() + ggtitle(i))

ppl <- list(p1 = arrangeGrob(grobs=pl[1:4]),
            p2 = arrangeGrob(grobs=pl[5:6]),
            p3 = arrangeGrob(grobs=pl[7]))

class(ppl) <- c("arrangelist", class(pl))

ggsave("multipage.pdf", ppl)
```

[image]