# Arrange multiple ggplots from a list on multiple pages with specified page breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to take plots from a list and output a multipage pdf. I can do this easily using gridExtra:marrangeGrob however I'm having issues with getting the page breaks in the right place. My data is in sets of 7 so I would like 4 pages with two plots on each page and then a break after the 7th plot with the 8th starting on a new page (as with after the 14th, 21st etc.).

My list contains (currently 84 ggplots, could be more in the future)

I looked at [ggplot list of plots to one pdf with different page layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049296/ggplot-list-of-plots-to-one-pdf-with-different-page-layouts) but I don't want to have to set up each page individually as there are so many of them (I also might want to change to 3 or 4 per page once I have the initial ones and don't want to have to re-work.

I've made an example using the diamonds dataframe, assuming I want to split the pages so plots from two different clarities aren't on the same page

```
egsplitdf <- diamonds %>% distinct(color, clarity) %>% arrange(clarity)
egPlotfun <- function(i, filterdf){
  dat = filter(diamonds, color == filterdf[["color"]][i] & clarity == 
       filterdf[["clarity"]][i])
  ggplot(dat, aes(x= x, y = y))+
       geom_point()+
       labs(title = paste(filterdf[["clarity"]][i], filterdf[["color"]][i]))
}

egPlots <- lapply(1:56, egPlotfun,filterdf = egsplitdf)
ArrangedPlots <- marrangeGrob(egPlots, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
ggsave("egNotsplit.pdf", ArrangedPlots, height = 10,width = 7)
```

but this just has the plots continuously with no breaks after 7 etc. 
I also tried splitting my plots into a list of

```
plotseq <- lapply(0:8,function(x) seq(from = (x*7+1), length.out = 7))
ListofPlots <- lapply(plotseq, function(x) lapply(x, egPlotfun, filterdf = egsplitdf ))
testSplit <-marrangeGrob(ListofPlots , nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
ggsave("TrySplit.pdf", testSplit, height = 10,width = 7)
```

but this gives:
"Error in gList(list(list(data = list(carat = c(0.32, 1.01, 0.43, 1.22,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList""

Any ideas?

Comment: Tentative suggestion, as I don't know your actual dataset, but would it be possible to use `facet_wrap` on each set of data? You can subset your data & plot all 7 (or whatever the number may be) as 1 ggplot object, & then save each plot to 1 page.

Comment: Haha, I started with a facet_wrap/facet_grid but I wanted each plot to have a subtitle and title (not all within the facets I was breaking it up on) and couldn't suss out how to do that. Might have ended up being easier to do it that way though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

[image]

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

pl <- lapply(1:84, function(i) ggplot() + ggtitle(i))

spl <- split(pl, (seq_along(pl)-1) %/% 7)
ppl <- lapply(spl, function(g) marrangeGrob(grobs = g, layout_matrix = matrix(c(1,2))))

pdf("test.pdf")
print(ppl)
dev.off()
```

Comment: Thanks! This mostly works. layout_matrix doesn't seem to work with marrangeGrob (only arrangeGrob) but I used ppl <- lapply(spl, function(g) marrangeGrob(grobs = g, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)) and that does. I was hoping to get the page numbering right (with the is just repeats 1 to 4) but I can live without it unless you have any sneaky suggestions?

Comment: I'm using a dev version where layout_matrix can be passed to marrangeGrob. For the title you can try `marrangeGrob(..., top = quote(paste("page", g, "of", length(spl) * pages )))`

Comment: Ah, ok, I'll stick with the version I have at the moment. That gives me the correct total amount of pages but not which individual page its up to (repeats 1:4 out of 48), I tried fiddling to fix count through the lists but doesn't seem to be working. No stress the page numbers aren't a big deal.